# Getting unicode output from python unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unittest

I have the following test:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    #pylint:disable=invalid-name
    def test_string_matches(self):
        self.assertEqual(u'你好', u'好')
```

This gives me the following output in the shell:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_string_matches (test.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in test_string_matches
    self.assertEqual(u'你好', u'好')
AssertionError: u'\u4f60\u597d' != u'\u597d'
- \u4f60\u597d
? -
+ \u597d
```

however if I run:

```
print '你好'
```

in the terminal, I get the expected output: `你好`

Is there a way to get python unittest to output the actual unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are still using Python 2.x? If you switch to Python 3.x then the exception will display the way you expect.

```
$ python3 t.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_string_matches (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 7, in test_string_matches
    self.assertEqual(u'你好', u'好')
AssertionError: '你好' != '好'
- 你好
? -
+ 好


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Not a real reason apart from this is an old project, so there's no way of getting that output in python 2.7?

Comment: Unfortunately I think Python 2 will display the escape codes even in the optional `msg` parameter for the `assertEqual()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get this working on Python2 the only way I have found to fix the problem is to force the system's encoding to `utf-8`:

```py
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```